# Why did John Cale remove a bullet from the gun?

Tags: white-house-down

A few days ago, I watched *White House Down* (2013). At one point, John Cale gives his gun to someone to be stored, and after removing the magazine, he takes one bullet out of it.

Why did he do that?

Comment: He took a round out of the magazine, or he took it out of the gun after removing the magazine?

Comment: Because that bullet was in the guns chamber not the magazine. In other words it was ready to fire without a new round being taken from the magazine

Comment: ohhhh ok thank you, scene was fast for me , didn't notice where did he take it out from

Answer (score 7):

Most semi-automatic pistols that use a magazine (versus a revolver), have the bullets in a removable magazine. In order to fire the pistol the first time, the operator slides the barrel assembly to the rear and releases it, which both cocks the weapon and loads the first round (bullet) into the chamber.

In order to completely 'safe' the weapon, which would be done before turning it in to the armory or to someone to hold, which is what that scene is showing, the operator might,

1. Put the weapon on safe, by clicking the safe lever
2. Remove the magazine
3. and again, pull the barrel assembly to the rear, which ejects the round from the chamber
4. Finally, the operator would then slowly lower the hammer to un-cock the weapon.

You may have seen this being done in many movies and TV police procedurals.